# Remove the language tag from bottom panel in inno set up

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I want to remove the Language tag from the bottom panel..Like in below screen it shows NORSK..as i have Norwegian as my selected language for installation..

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear the `BeveledLabel` message key value from the script using the [`[Messages]`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_messagessection.htm) section (or clear this key value directly in your `*.isl` language file to make this change to be permanent):

```
[Messages]
BeveledLabel=
```

Comment: thanks..TLama...I figured it out....i was too fast to post this here...should have checked this myself. :)

Comment: You're welcome! Interesting is that in my InnoSetup 5.5.0 Unicode distribution I have no value for this key for all language files, what version of InnoSetup are you using anyway ?

Comment: I am using Inno setup compiler version 5.5.0(a)....Actually this was defined explicitly in the script...i have removed this....so this is fine now.... :)

Comment: just in curiosity..can we use gif images in inno setup...actually i want to show a loading image when user clicks on next button in license page...as it takes some time to verify the license from server and return a response..back..i am calling a separate .net exe to check this from inside the inno setup... all this process goes on click on next button on license page.

Comment: It would have been the `TGraphic` descendant, but looking at the [`classes reference`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptclasses.htm), except `TBitmap` class there's no other image type class specified. So currently there's no way (even when the canvas class is ready for this).